# Java : Hibernate is too much slow

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jdbc

I'm working on a a swing application, to handle the data I chose Hibernate because of its performance. now that I did 80% of the work. I found out that the application is too slow, like forever waiting. I googled it and found that if there are many data Hibernate is not the best choice. I didn't know that and the problem is that my database is complicated many associations, joins , sets ...
I don't have the time to start all over again ! Help please

here is a snippet of code, this is how I retrieve data every entity has a similar class

```
public class CoursCrud {
SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();  
Session session ;
 public ArrayList<Object> findCoursByCoursId( int id){
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findLastCours(){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findLastCours");
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findAllCours(){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findAllCours");
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findProfByCoursId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findProfByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}

  public ArrayList<Object> findGroupeByCoursId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findGroupeByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findGroupeByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findGroupeByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findSalleByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findSalleByCreneauId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findProfByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findProfByCreneauId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCreneauFromCoursByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCreneauFromCoursByCreneauId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();

    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCoursByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursByCreneauId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}

  public ArrayList<Object> findSalleByCoursId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findSalleByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCreneauByCoursId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCreneauByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}

public   ArrayList<Object> findCoursByGroupeId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursByGroupeId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;
}
public   ArrayList<Object> findCoursBySalleId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursBySalleId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;
}
public   ArrayList<Object> findProfBySalleId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findProfBySalleId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;
}


  public int findIndex(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    ArrayList<Object> cours =C.findAllCours(); 
    int i=0;
    for(Object cu: cours){
        i++;
        if(((Cours) cu).getId() == id){
            break;
        }
    }
    return --i;
}
public void createData( Object p){
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(p);  
        transaction.commit();  
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }  
}
public void updateData( Object p){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    session.beginTransaction();  

    session.update(p);  
    session.getTransaction().commit();  

    session.close();
}

public void CoursEmpty(){  
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    List<Object> cc = C.findAllCours();
    for(Object c: cc){
        C.deleteCoursByCoursId(((Cours)c).getId());
    }
}
public void deleteCoursByCoursId(int id){
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();     
        Cours c = (Cours) C.findCoursByCoursId(id).get(0);
        session.delete(c);
        transaction.commit();  
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }   
}

public void deleteCoursCreneauByCoursId(int id){
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();     
        Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("deleteCoursCreneauByCoursId");
        Q.setLong("id", id).executeUpdate();
        transaction.commit();  
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println("Not succ !! \n");
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }   
}

  public ArrayList<Object> findCreneauIndisponibiliteByCoursId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCreneauIndisponibiliteByCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCoursIndisponibleByCreneauId(int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursIndisponibleByCreneauId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCoursByClassCoursId( int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursByClassCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public void deleteCoursByClassCours(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    for(Object o: C.findCoursByClassCoursId(id)){
        C.deleteCoursSeanceByCoursId(((Cours)o).getId());
        C.deleteCoursCreneauByCoursId(((Cours)o).getId());
        C.deleteCoursByCoursId(((Cours)o).getId());
    }
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findGroupeByClassCoursId( int id){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findGroupeByClassCoursId");
    Q.setLong("id", id);
    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Integer> findIndexGroupebyClassCours(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    GroupeCrud Gc= new GroupeCrud();
    ArrayList<Object> groupeSelectedList= C.findGroupeByClassCoursId(id);
    ArrayList<Object> groupeList= Gc.findAllGroupe();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexSelectedList= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Alert a= new Alert();
    for(Object m: groupeList){
        for(Object ms: groupeSelectedList){
            if(((Groupe) m).getId() == ((Groupe) ms).getId() ){
                indexSelectedList.add(groupeList.indexOf(m));
            }
        }
    }
    return indexSelectedList;
}
  public ArrayList<Integer> findIndexSeancebyClassCours(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    SeanceCrud sC=new SeanceCrud();
    ArrayList<Seance> SeanceSelectedList = new ArrayList<Seance>();
    for(Object o: C.findCoursByClassCoursId(id)){
        for(Object v: sC.findSeanceByCoursId(((Cours)o).getId())){
            SeanceSelectedList.add((Seance)v);
        }
    }

    ArrayList<Object> seanceList= sC.findAllSeance();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexSelectedList= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Alert a= new Alert();
    for(Object m: seanceList){
        for(Seance ms: SeanceSelectedList){
            if(((Seance) m).getId() == ms.getId() ){
                indexSelectedList.add(seanceList.indexOf(m));
            }
        }
    }
    return indexSelectedList;
}
public void deleteCoursSeanceByCoursId(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction transaction = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();     
        Cours c = (Cours) C.findCoursByCoursId(id).get(0);
        c.getCoursSeance().clear();
        session.update(c);
        transaction.commit();  
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        transaction.rollback();
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }   
}
  public ArrayList<Integer> findIndexIndisponibilitebyCoursId(int id){
    CoursCrud C= new CoursCrud();
    CreneauCrud cC= new CreneauCrud();
    ArrayList<Object> IndispoSelectedList= C.findCreneauIndisponibiliteByCoursId(id);
    ArrayList<Object> creneauList= cC.findAllCreneau();
    ArrayList<Integer> indexindispoSelectedList= new ArrayList<Integer>();

    Alert a= new Alert();
    for(Object m: creneauList){
        for(Object ms: IndispoSelectedList){
            if(((Creneau) m).getId() == ((Creneau) ms).getId() ){
                indexindispoSelectedList.add(creneauList.indexOf(m));
            }
        }
    }
    return indexindispoSelectedList;
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCoursIndisponibleByCreneauIdAndCoursId(int idCreneau, int idCours){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursIndisponibleByCreneauIdAndCoursId");
    Q.setLong("idCours", idCours);
    Q.setLong("idCreneau", idCreneau);

    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
  public ArrayList<Object> findCoursByCreneauIdAndGroupeId(int idCreneau, int idGroupe){

    session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    Query Q = session.getNamedQuery("findCoursByCreneauIdAndGroupeId");
    Q.setLong("idGroupe", idGroupe);
    Q.setLong("idCreneau", idCreneau);

    List<Object> objet = Q.list();
    session.close(); 
    return (ArrayList<Object>) objet;   
}
```

Comment: It might help if you post some code snippets where the performance is poor. You may need to monitor the database to make sure you aren't having locking issues. ORM is not well suited to Batch processing but for normal OLTP applications it is fine.

Comment: As you are using swing and hibernate, you mean slow that your application freeze? may be you want to use hibernate with lucene, queries in db are fast? may be you have n+1 problem!! take care of that! Try to use `show_sql=true` try to avoid `n+1`

Answer (score 1):

no this is definitely not the case. hibernate is one of the best ORM implementations out there. you should figure out your queries, db indexes and other optimizations. The biggest bottleneck in most of the apps if the DB.
if you see, hibernate internally uses jdbc and fires SQL queries. it reduces your work a lot and provides very concrete implementations and interfaces.
please provide more description to your problem to explain why you feel hibernate is the culprite and not anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try to narrow down what exactly is the problem.  Your problems could be fixed with proper indexes etc.  Maybe provide more information.

Usually the slowest part of DB is the DB connection creation.  Are you using DB Pooling?

Comment: No I don't use it. I read that creating every time the session factory could be the reason. in my code for every operation to retrieve data from db I created and closed it.

Comment: DB connection pooling is good.  But it isn't a show-stopper usually.

Comment: As you state, it could be the reason.  I am not sure where you are calling DB code from, but if you are creating a sessionFactory connection from scratch I feel this would be slow.  Can you not keep the previosuly created DB Connection?

Comment: @TonyEnnis can be though.  http://serverfault.com/questions/51317/connecting-to-mysql-over-tcp-hangs-for-3-seconds

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that there are complicated relations between DB entities, you may want to check out Hibernate "lazy loading" if you have not.

Lazy loading controls when and how related entities are loaded to memory, in many cases, it could lead to huge performance improvements.

Comment: in some entities I was obliged to set it as EAGER to delete some data from join tables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you returning a large data set and then using Java to filter it to a small number of records?  I've seen it before.  Transferring tons of data over the network only to discard most of it is a common mistake.